# PHP can't connect with Oracle Database

Tags: php, oracle, apache

I have installed Vertrigo Server with [**Apache 2.0**]  &  [**PHP 5.2.14**] on Windows XP X32 but **Vertrigo** server doesn't includes OCI8.DLL extension for Oracle Database. When I tried to copy this DLL file from another version of PHP I got Apache error:

> [v_apache.exe]: The application cannot start because php5.dll is
>   missing.

Without this DLL file everything is wokrking OK, but I need to connect with oracle Database. Have you any solutions how to add **OCI8.DLL** extension in that version of PHP and Apache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time searching over the internet finaly I found soltion for it. Strange is that Apache doesn't alert error about real problem, it just says that problem is with 80 port, even when 80 port is free.

**Solution is very simle:** I just installed [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) and after averithing was running correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest way is to use Zend Server CE.
It has latest stable apache with latest stable PHP stack, also with oci libraries (and much more).

Download for [free](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) (registration required).